# Regex google analytics - Filter homepage and directories -

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm trying to create a new Google Analytics view filter to show frontpage, and some website using regular expression but haven't been successful.

```
(\/$|^\/app\/|^\/page\/|\/features)
```

Pages I want to show:

```
/

/app/test

/app/a/t

/page/john

/page/marisa

/features
```

User generated content that i don't want to show in the view:

```
/any-other-url-not-mentioned-before
```

Comment: are those exact matches or you just showed example pages or do you want anything that starts with `/app` or `/page` or `/features`?

Comment: I want anything that starts with /page and /app. Exact match for /features.

Comment: i've updated my answer to match features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checks if the provided value is an exact match for root `/` or if the page path starts with either `/app` or `/features` or `/page`. After the starting requirement, zero or more groups in the format `/letter-or-number` can follow.

```
 (^\/$|^\/app|^\/page|^\/features$)(\/\w*)*
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Just to confirm even if I create an exact filter  in google analytics like `^\?features$`  if the url contains an utm code like  `/features?&utm_medium=email` it would still appear in google analytics view right?

Comment: if you are filtering by request URI it would NOT. More info [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034380?hl=en)

Comment: @PedMor any luck?

Comment: If the answer did resolve your question, please mark your question as resolved. Thanks

Comment: If I want to filter to show only /es or /es/ or /es/school but NOT eskkkkk, how could I do it properly?  I am trying to filter by pages in localized languages > (^\/$|^\/app|^\/es|^\/pt|^\/fr|^\/de|^\/blog|^\/page|)(\/\w*)*